# How to beat Baron Raymondo on the ipad version

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

How to beat Baron Raymondo, I got a sloop of war,  I can board him within the first year but it is really hard to avoid the attacks with a long sword. Also when I avoid the middle attack by going back+mid (on iPad) my character cannot counter attack as he blocks the next attack.

Anyone has tips about how to beat him ?

Comment: are you using the rapier as your sword?  if you can't counter attack fast enough you are probably not using the rapier.  Granted I haven't played the ipad version to know if its any different.

Comment: Also using the middle attack to counter, which is faster then the other 2

Comment: I was not using the rapier but longsword, I will try using the rapier. I find that on ipad the swipes do not register 100% of the time unless you do long swipes.